# In grails, is there a loop that behaves like findAll but does not collect object?

Tags: grails

Currently, im using **findAll**. But I dont need the list that it returns. **return** doesnt work in **each** so I could not use it.

In grails, is there a loop that matched my need or should I use **for** loop?

Comment: Not clear what you need? Can you elaborate with an example? Have you tried find() http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find() ?

Answer (score 0):

If it makes any sense I believe you are trying to use it as a state rather than wanting the results in which case I doubt you would need findAll

so something like

```
def user =  User.findByUsername('username')
```

Now 
if you did

```
if (user) {
//do something
}
```

That would tell you  there is something found or maybe:

```
int size =  (User.findAllByUsername('username')?.size()) ?: 0

println "found ${size} records"
```

Ofcourse if you did

```
User.findAll{}
```

Thats all then you iterate through it find what you want

instead if you did

```
//def aa = User.findAll{user=='username'}?.size()
def aa = User.findAll{user=='username'}
if (aa ) {
println "we have something "
}
```